# Smartband 2 Access heart rate variability

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

So far the Smartband 2 is a great device and one of it's core features is the measurement of the heart rate variability (HRV). As I have already read through all the APIs that the Smartband 2 is posting it's data to, I am still wondering if it is possible to access the heart rate variability directly.

So far it seems that I can only get ALL other data except for the heart rate variablity form the Smartband 2. Am I missing something? Is it maybe possible to calculate the heart rate variability from any of the other values that I can access via the APIs?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API available in SmartBand 2 to retrieve the Heart Rate Variability.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you have any plans to add this feature to the API?

Comment: I can't comment on any road map related questions but I have mentioned it to our team for future consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Both sets of the Google Fit APIs work with three types of data: Public data types, Custom data types, and Shareable data types. SmartBand 2 provides the following Public data types to the Google Fitness Store:

- google.step_count.delta (steps)
- google.heart_rate.bpm (heart rate in
  bpm)
- google.activity.segment (sleeping, walking, running)

[Use SmartBand 2 sensor data for innovative Android and iOS applications](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2015/09/10/use-smartband-2-sensor-data-for-innovative-android-and-ios-applications/)

Comment: This however does not answer my question regarding the heart rate variability. It only says that I can receive the beats per minute, which is absolutely not the same.